# what's the value of drop_path_keep_prob used for Auto DeepLab

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

The default `drop_path_keep_prob` is 1.0 defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/train.py#L147).
But the `Drop Path` doesn't contribute anything if the `drop_path_keep_prob` is not less than 1.0.

What's the exact value used for training the Auto DeepLab?

Answer (score 0):

Got response from the author of the Auto DeepLab via email,

Answer:

`drop_path_keep_prob=0.8`